# Replaying the sound as many times as button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have the following code:

```
    if (someId.matches("A") || someId.matches("a")) {
        tvLetCap.setText("A");
        tvLetLow.setText("a");
        ivLetterIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
        btnDisplayWord.setText("A is for APPLE");
        mpSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
        mpSound.setLooping(false);
        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*try {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypack.testing/" + R.raw.sound);
                    mpSound.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),uri);
                    mpSound.prepare();
                    */
                    mpSound.start();
                    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnStop.setOnClickListener(stopSound);
                /*}
                catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e("REPLAYING", "prepare() failed");
                }*/
            }
        });
        mpSound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mpSound.release();
                btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

It plays fine with the codes commented out but whenever I try to replay the file my app FC. The sound file is located in `res/raw/sound.mp3`

How can I modify the code so it plays as many times as the `btnPlay` is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You've released the media player.  If you want to reuse it, don't do that.

Comment: Use it only during onDestroy()?

Comment: Yes, if that's the only time you're done with it.  But once you call that, you can't use that object anymore.

Comment: Until I return to the activity I am guessing?

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods for mediaplayer...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Maybe you need to use mpSound.reset() in onClick method for button (some time ago i had such mistake :p)? :)

Comment: There is a question - why? If it works, just use it ;) Maybe it is not super optimal, but we don't write artificial intelligence or solving optimization problems (then we should probably use at least c++ language :P).. Phones today are enough powerfull to restart media player in few millisecs (and have 100 another tasks in the same time), so we can exploit it :P